# How to shorten IF statement with require() inside?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I'm trying to make the if statement shorter, to require a less gas it the case of emergency, here how it looks like:

```
if (input == token0) {
    require(amount0Out > amount, "1");
}
else if  (input != token0) {
    require(amount1Out > amount, "2");
}
```

So I tried something like this but it doesn't produce the same result, actually it always fails with error "1".

```
input == token0
  ? require(amount0Out > amount, "1")
  : require(amount1Out > amount, "2");
```

So what is the smart way to make if statement here?

Comment: what is the type of input and token0 ? address or uint ?

Comment: I have tried a simple example and for me those two implementations were equivalent, I think your input causing the problem, so can you give a complete example? and by the way, are you sure the second one will save you gas? have you tried it with enabled   optimizer :/ ?